# pandas value_counts with bins argument

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this,

```
col1
1
2
3
2
2
3
1
1
2
3
1
1
3
3
1
1
3
```

When I compute

`print df['col1'].value_counts(bins=2)`

It gives me,

```
(0.997, 2.0]    11
(2.0, 3.0]       6
Name: col1, dtype: int64
```

Result is good. But in index it gives mixed of `(`&`]`.
Why it behaves like this. Because I want to preserve index as a new column like below.

`temp=pd.DataFrame(df['col1'].value_counts(bins=2).reset_index()).rename(columns={'index':'bin'})`

Is there any way to keep same parenthesis either '(' or ']'. or should I clean (replace) that by another line of code?

Please help to understand the problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Waht is expected output?

Comment: in index columns either it should contains only () or []. I don't want mixed of parenthesis. ex: (0.997, 2.0] it can be (0.997, 2.0) or [0.997, 2.0]

Comment: It is called [Intervalindex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.IntervalIndex.html), so need convert it to lists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use if need convert [Intervalindex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.IntervalIndex.html) to `tuple`s:

```
df1 = df['col1'].value_counts(bins=2).reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'bin'})
df1['bins'] = [(x.left, x.right) for x in df1['bin']]
print (df1)
            bin  col1          bins
0  (0.997, 2.0]    11  (0.997, 2.0)
1    (2.0, 3.0]     6    (2.0, 3.0)
```

Or to `list`s:

```
df1['bins'] = [[x.left, x.right] for x in df1['bin']]
print (df1)
            bin  col1          bins
0  (0.997, 2.0]    11  [0.997, 2.0]
1    (2.0, 3.0]     6    [2.0, 3.0]
```

Also if want `string`s:

```
df1['bins'] = ['({}, {})'.format(x.left, x.right) for x in df1['bin']]
print (df1)
            bin  col1          bins
0  (0.997, 2.0]    11  (0.997, 2.0)
1    (2.0, 3.0]     6    (2.0, 3.0)
```

And for new columns:

```
df1[['l', 'r']] = pd.DataFrame([(x.left, x.right) for x in df1['bin']])
print (df1)
            bin  col1      l    r
0  (0.997, 2.0]    11  0.997  2.0
1    (2.0, 3.0]     6  2.000  3.0
```

Answer (score 2):

It uses `(` and `]` to indicate open and closed for intervals. Your bin is an interval actually, for example `(2.0, 3.0]` indicates exclusive 2 and inclusive 3.

```
(2.0, 3.0]: 2.0 < x <= 3.0
```

If you need to change the format of the bins, use the following command after the `reset_index`:

```
df['Bins'] = df.iloc[:, 0].apply(lambda x: '[{}: {}]'.format(x.left, x.right))
```

**Output**

```
df['Bins']
Out[121]:
0    [-0.002: 0.0]
1     [0.0: 0.001]
Name: Bins, dtype: object
```